# "This looks like him" or "This looks like he"?

Tags: linguistics, grammatical-case, copular-verbs

Another, easier [case question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/335453/i-am-who-whom-g-d-made-me):

Obviously, of the two variants

> **This looks like him**

and

> **This looks like he**

the first seems more naturally idiomatic. However, is it grammatically correct?

I think the not-necessarily-separable questions at work here are:

- Whether "to look like" is a linking verb in English ("This looks [~to be] he") (likely it [is](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159073/looks-really-well-or-looks-really-good));
- Whether "to look like" is an idiographic construction following its own rules, or rather an ellipticization or reduction of, say  "This looks like [it is] he" or "This looks like he [looks (/does)]."

...The only doubt in my mind about whether "This looks like he" is correct is the *Columbia Guide* citation [here](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001061.html), which argues:

> Than is both a subordinating conjunction, as in She is wiser than I
>   am, and a preposition, as in She is wiser than me. As subject of the
>   clause introduced by the conjunction than, the pronoun must be
>   nominative, and as object of the preposition than, the following
>   pronoun must be in the objective case. Since the following verb am is
>   often dropped or “understood,” we regularly hear than I and than me.

Is there a linguistic basis for the *Columbia Guide's* assertion, as there clearly is for the alternative? Or is this simply an argument between prescriptivism, realism, and second-wave prescriptivism?

*Cf. 
"He plays like I"
"I do it better than she"*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87658/discussion-on-question-by-sah-this-looks-like-him-or-this-looks-like-he).

Answer (score 1):

As 'like' is a preposition here, the pronoun after it must be 'him'.

See an example from Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:

***like***
 preposition

:typical of

// was like him to do that

According to Cambridge Dictionary:

***LIKE***
preposition

Like means ‘similar to’.

We often use it with verbs of the senses such as look, sound, feel, taste, seem:

My sister is like my mother. (My sister and my mother are similar)

Comment: Really interesting example in "[...]was like him to do that." But I think my question is even more basic than you answer. I am asking, approximately, how we know "like" is a preposition rather than a conjunction in the sentence "That looks like []."

Comment: Yes, "like" means "similar to" as a preposition. It means "similarly to" as a conjunction. I'm asking how we know for sure which one it is here. P.S. I'm a native English speaker.